# How do I add new text to elements of the same class without overwriting my existing elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Sorry if my question isn't clear. 
Basically I have the following code

HTML:

```
    <div class="container">
        <textarea class="newText" placeholder="Have something to say?"></textarea>
        <button class="btn btn-default btn-sm">Post</button>
    </div>
<div class="main">
    <div class="postFeed">
        <ul class="postFeedElements">
            <li>
                <ul class="iconList pull-right">
                    <li> <span class="remove glyphicon glyphicon-remove" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Remove"></span>

                    </li>
                </ul>
                <li>
                     <h4 class="noSelect"> Text</h4>

                </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

JQuery:

```
var newPost = function () {
$('.btn').click(function () {
    var post = $('.newText').val();
    $('<div class="postFeed"><ul class="postFeedElements"><li><ul class="iconList pull-right"><li><span class="remove glyphicon glyphicon-remove" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Remove Post"></span></li></ul><li><h4 class="noSelect"></h4></li></ul></div>').appendTo('.container');
    $('.noSelect').text(post);
    $('.newText').val(" ");
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/r8umr1m3/

Text input in the texarea gets passed into a new heading of an identical div element.
Currently when new text is passed to a new div, it overwrites any existing text in existing divs as each heading element shares the same class. How can I make it so each element has different text based on the input in the textarea whilst still keeping the same class?

Thanks,

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/r8umr1m3/8/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Insert the text itself within the big string you have in the selector

```
'....<h4 class="noSelect">'+post+'</h4> ....'
```

and remove

```
$('.noSelect').text(post);
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/r8umr1m3/2/)

Comment: If you are using this solution, you have to delete `$('.noSelect').text(post);` as well

Answer (score 1):

```
/* remove */
var remove = function () {
    $(document).on('click', '.remove', function () {
        $(this).parents('.postFeed').remove();
    });
}
$(document).ready(remove);

var newPost = function () {
    $('.btn').click(function () {
        var post = $('.newText').val();
        var element = $('<div class="postFeed"><ul class="postFeedElements"><li><ul class="iconList pull-right"><li><span class="remove glyphicon glyphicon-remove" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Remove Post"></span></li></ul><li><h4 class="noSelect"></h4></li></ul></div>');
        element.appendTo('.container');
        element.text(post);
        $('.newText').val(" ");
    });
};
$(document).ready(newPost);
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/r8umr1m3/5/)**

Answer (score 1):

It's less expensive, resource-wise, to manipulate and modify the new content before attaching it to the DOM.

```
var newPost = function () {
    $('.btn').click(function () {
        var post = $('.newText').val(),
            newContent = $('<div class="postFeed"><ul class="postFeedElements"><li><ul class="iconList pull-right"><li><span class="remove glyphicon glyphicon-remove" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Remove Post"></span></li></ul><li><h4 class="noSelect"></h4></li></ul></div>');

        $('.noSelect', newContent).text(post); //manipulate detached content
        $('.container').append( newContent ); //attach content
        $('.newText').val(" ");
    });
};
$(document).ready(newPost);
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using jquery to select for `.noSelect` you can save the new element in a variable and use `.find` to find `.noSelect` *within* that new element. This will update only the element you add instead of all elements with class `noSelect`:

```
var newPost = function () {
    $('.btn').click(function () {
        var post = $('.newText').val();
        var $newEle = $('<div class="postFeed"><ul class="postFeedElements"><li><ul class="iconList pull-right"><li><span class="remove glyphicon glyphicon-remove" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Remove Post"></span></li></ul><li><h4 class="noSelect"></h4></li></ul></div>')
        $newEle.appendTo('.container');
        $newEle.find('.noSelect').text(post);
        $('.newText').val(" ");
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace below code with yours :

```
var newPost = function () {
    $('.btn').click(function () {
        var post = $('.newText').val();
        $('<div class="postFeed"><ul class="postFeedElements"><li><ul class="iconList pull-right">             <li><span class="remove glyphicon glyphicon-remove" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Remove Post"></span></li></ul><li><h4 class="noSelect">'+post+'</h4></li></ul></div>').appendTo('.container');
        //$('.noSelect').text(post);
        $('.newText').val(" ");
    });
};
```

Just remove "$('.noSelect').text(post);" and add post value between you h4 tag

Answer (score 0):

You just need to save the postfeed div that you are creating into a variable and and add post text to that variable.

I have update your jquery code below:-

```
var newPost = function () {
    $('.btn').click(function () {
        var post = $('.newText').val();
        // Save the post feed div in a variable
        var newHeader = $('<div class="postFeed"><ul class="postFeedElements"><li><ul class="iconList pull-right"><li><span class="remove glyphicon glyphicon-remove" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Remove Post"></span></li></ul><li><h4 class="noSelect"></h4></li></ul></div>').appendTo('.container');
// update the text in the newly created div
        newHeader.text(post);
        $('.newText').val(" ");
});
```

Adding .text directly to a class will update all the divs with that class.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/zro4b1g7/) is the correction. Basically you need to get the created `div` as a variable and add the new text to it.

Here is the javascript:

```
/* remove */
var remove = function () {
    $(document).on('click', '.remove', function () {
        $(this).parents('.postFeed').remove();
    });
}
$(document).ready(remove);

var newPost = function () {
    $('.btn').click(function () {
        var post = $('.newText').val();
        // get the new div as a variable
        var newDiv = $('<div class="postFeed"><ul class="postFeedElements"><li><ul class="iconList pull-right">             <li><span class="remove glyphicon glyphicon-remove" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Remove Post"></span></li></ul><li><h4 class="noSelect"></h4></li></ul></div>');

        // append the new div
        newDiv.appendTo('.container');

        // set the text to this new div
        newDiv.text(post);
        $('.newText').val(" ");
    });
};
$(document).ready(newPost);
```

Answer (score 0):

Intead of `$('.noSelect').text(post);` you can select the last and the element before the last one and set them.

```
   $($('.noSelect')[$('.noSelect').length-1]).text(post);
   $($('.noSelect')[$('.noSelect').length-2]).text(post);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mrv9tr83/

Hope it solves you problem

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to write whole html at javascript as it already at the html. Use clone() to get the existing html. After then update last noselect text under container div

**Script**

```
/* remove */
var remove = function () {
    $(document).on('click', '.remove', function () {
        $(this).parents('.postFeed').remove();
    });
}

$(document).ready(remove);

var newPost = function () {
    $('.btn').click(function () {
        var post = $('.newText').val();
        var clone = $(".main > .postFeed").clone();
        $(".container").append(clone);
        $('.container  .noSelect').last().text(post);
        $('.newText').val(" ");
    });
};

$(document).ready(newPost);
```